# Fullcalendar - jump to agendaDay from month view when date is picked

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm having trouble getting this functionality to work. I would like for the user to be able to jump to the agendaDay view from the month view after selecting a date. Can anyone suggest a way to achieve that functionality?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the [dayClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/) event, along with [changeView](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/changeView/) and [gotoDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/)

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
  if(view.name != 'month')
    return;

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay')
                .fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
},
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I did it in the select option instead of dayClick and it worked just the same.

Answer (score 11):

Just the updated answer for the new versions 2.x.x.

You have to call the methods this way:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
```

because chaining for the method calls is not implemented (fullCalendar() call to method returns method response instead of JQuery object).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
 $("#calendar").fullCalendar({

    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

        //alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
        //alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
        //alert('Current view: ' + view.name);
        if (view.name != 'month')
            return;

        if (view.name == 'month') {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
        }

    },
```